# How to get nested key values in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Can someone please tell me how to echo or use nested key values. I basically get() this collection and I'm using foreach to do some further calculations.
My relation structure is zone.shipping and here I want to obtain fuel and emergency from the nest.

```
[{"id":614,"weight":"25.000","rate":"150.640","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":5,"zone":"e","company":1,"shipping":{"id":1,"company":"fedex","fuel":"19.50","emergency":"1.35","source":1}}},

{"id":1838,"weight":"25.000","rate":"179.610","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":17,"zone":"7","company":2,"shipping":{"id":2,"company":"dhl","fuel":"19.75","emergency":"0.50","source":1}}},

{"id":2414,"weight":"25.000","rate":"263.320","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":24,"zone":"6","company":3,"shipping":{"id":3,"company":"ups","fuel":"24.00","emergency":"1.30","source":1}}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [data_get()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get)

Answer (score 0):

**Take your array in one variable just I had taken for reference**

```
$data = [{"id":614,"weight":"25.000","rate":"150.640","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":5,"zone":"e","company":1,"shipping":{"id":1,"company":"fedex","fuel":"19.50","emergency":"1.35","source":1}}},

{"id":1838,"weight":"25.000","rate":"179.610","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":17,"zone":"7","company":2,"shipping":{"id":2,"company":"dhl","fuel":"19.75","emergency":"0.50","source":1}}},

{"id":2414,"weight":"25.000","rate":"263.320","unit":"kg","detail":"normal","zone":{"id":24,"zone":"6","company":3,"shipping":{"id":3,"company":"ups","fuel":"24.00","emergency":"1.30","source":1}}}];
```

**For fetch value**

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
   $fuel[] = $value['zone']['shipping']['fuel'];
   $emergency[] = $value['zone']['shipping']['emergency'];
}
```

**Main thing how you can get fuel and emergency is**

```
$value['zone']['shipping']['fuel'];
$value['zone']['shipping']['emergency'];
```

**For specific index also you can get as:**

```
$data[0]['zone']['shipping']['fuel'];
$data[0]['zone']['shipping']['emergency'];
```

Comment: This looks right. I'll give it a try soon.
For now I did this and it has worked
        $fuel           =   $rate->zone()->first()->shipping()->first()->fuel;
        $emergency      =   $rate->zone()->first()->shipping()->first()->emergency;